# How do I use jquery to get the Next/Previous Page(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery

when click next button will redirect to next li

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li ><a href="news">News</a></li>
        <li ><a href="Sports">Sports</a></li>
  </ul>
<a href="#" class="next">next</a>
<a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
```

Comment: your links dont makes any sense... href="Home"? like href = "../../Home.html"?

Comment: @user1778606: Entirely possible that those links are handled by the server.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder. yeah, I guess so

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to cycle through those `<li>`s based on where the active class currently is?

Well, to get the next, you could use the ... [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method :)

```
$('.next').click(function(){
    var $current = $('li.active');
    var $next = $current.next();
    if ($next.length){ 
       window.location = $next.find('a').attr('href'); //I assume???
    } else {
       //let's wrap around to the first li in the list, per TJ's comment
       var $wrapAroundTarget = $current.siblings().first();
       window.location = $wrapAroundTarget.find('a').attr('href');
    }
});
```

And of course previous would be the same thing, but with the [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method instead of next, and, per TJ again, to wrap around to the last `<li>`, simply use `$current.siblings().last()`.

Comment: Perhaps `$current.siblings().first()` for the wrap-around? And similarly, `$current.siblings().last()` for wrap-around for previous?

Comment: Why are you using $ in your variables? Is that a convention for jQuery variables, or just a typo?

Comment: @jcsanyi - it's a convention for variables that hold jQuery result sets.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
$('a.next').click(function() {
    $('#mainmenu li.active').next().each(function () {
        window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    });
});

$('a.prev').click(function() {
    $('#mainmenu li.active').prev().each(function () {
        window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    });
});
```

If you can guarantee that the you don't try to go prev from the first link or next from the last one (by hiding the links, etc), the code could be simplified significantly:

```
$('a.next').click(function() {
    window.location = $('#mainmenu li.active').next().find('a').attr('href');
});

$('a.prev').click(function() {
    window.location = $('#mainmenu li.active').prev().find('a').attr('href');
});
```